# Encoding variation in scraped HTML code

Tags: javascript, python, html, perl, web-scraping

I used perl get() method to scrape a URL. I got the HTML code but as I extracted tamil content from the site it gives me strange text instead of tamil text. I used Firefox Inspector tool to view the HTML code it contains tamil content. But when I view source from menu it shows encoded strings. I used the following code to get the HTML

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::Simple;
 $content = get("http://www.arulvakku.com/biblecontent.php");

open www,">> foo";
select www;
print www $content;
 die "Couldn't get it!" unless defined $content;
```

and stored the HTML code in foo . When I open it up with Libreoffice writer it shows the webpage in tamil. But when I view the source code it gives me encodings . The equivalent codes in Firefox Inspector and HTML code are as folloes :

```
 <span class = "biblecontent">  தொடக்கத்தில் கடவுள் விண்ணுலகையும், மண்ணுலகையும் படைத்த பொழுது,   <span style="color:#D26900;font-size:16px"></span></span>
```

Scraped equivalent HTML code:

```
<span class="biblecontent">  &#2980;&#3018;&#2975;&#2965;&#3021;&#2965;&#2980;&#3021;&#2980;&#3007;&#2994;&#3021; &#2965;&#2975;&#2997;&#3009;&#2995;&#3021; &#2997;&#3007;&#2979;&#3021;&#2979;&#3009;&#2994;&#2965;&#3016;&#2991;&#3009;&#2990;&#3021;, &#2990;&#2979;&#3021;&#2979;&#3009;&#2994;&#2965;&#3016;&#2991;&#3009;&#2990;&#3021; &#2986;&#2975;&#3016;&#2980;&#3021;&#2980; &#2986;&#3018;&#2996;&#3009;&#2980;&#3009;,   <span style='color:#D26900;font-size:16px'></span></span>
```

How can I obtain the tamil content or how can I convert the HTML content back to tamil. Any other ways to obtain tamil or other language content HTML code is helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML::Entites module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Entities;
use utf8;

my $str = '&#3018;&#2975;&#2965;&#3021;&#2965;&#2980;&#3021;&#2980;&#3007;&#2994;&#3021; &#2965;&#2975;&#2997;&#3009;&#2995;';

print decode_entities($str);
```

Output:

```
ொடக்கத்தில் கடவுள
```

Comment: Thanks @user4035 I have found the answer to it @ http://mothereff.in/html-entities for decoding. It gives the correct text. But still I have to copy paste text. I have 1000 lines of text.

Comment: @xtreak No need to use an external website. You can decode directly in Perl. Just put `$content = decode_entities($content);` before `print www $content;`